# NodeJS Observable subscribe return nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, web-scraping, rxjs

I'm Building a web **scraper** using nodeJS ( TypeScript ) from multiple sites ( I'm new into this but learning from trying :"D ).

Anyway, the problem is on the `following code` When I `subscribe` and `console.log` the returning `value` as supposed! nothing happens!.

Even `console.log` for hard `string` inside `subscribe()` not showing!!!

But it *subscribes* I mean the function work but I need the data of course.

**The Constructor:**

```
constructor() {

   this.websitesUrls.subscribe(
       data => {
           this.intialScraping([data[0]]);
       }
   );
}
```

**The IntialScraping Method:**

```js
intialScraping(newsPapers: { title: string, href: string }[]) {

    console.log('Intializing scrapping');

    for (let i = 0; i < newsPapers.length; i++) {
        const newsPaper = newsPapers[i];

        switch (newsPaper.href) {
            case "http://test.com":
                console.log('Sracping on: ', newsPaper.title);

                let uri = newsPaper.href + '/%D8%A3%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D9%88%D8%AA%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B1'
                RxHR.get(uri)
                    .pipe(
                        map(data => {
                            let $ = cheerio.load(data.body);
                            const articlesUrl = $('#infinite .item > a').map(function (this: any) {
                                return $(this).attr('href')
                            }).get();

                            return articlesUrl;
                        }),
                        switchMap(urls => {
                            let data = [];

                            for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
                                const url = urls[i];

                                // console.log('start looping', url);


                                let data$ = RxHR.get(url).pipe(
                                    map(data => {

                                        let $ = cheerio.load(data.body);

                                        return {
                                            title: $('h1[itemprop=headline]').text().trim(),
                                            image: $('.article-image img').attr('src'),
                                            content: $('.details').text()
                                        };
                                    })
                                )

                                data.push(data$); // if i console here there is an output

                            } // loop ending

                            return forkJoin(data);
                        })
                    ).subscribe( data => {
                        console.log('Working'); // no-output
                        console.log(data[0].title); // no-output
                    })

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

On the above code, I **commented** on the `console.log` that **not working**!

> **Note: the data variable inside the 'pipe' 'switchMap' If I console it gives me the data!**

Comment: Generally, if something inside a `subscribe` function isn't working, it's because no data is making it to the end of the pipe. It could be that your `forkJoin` isn't emitting anything because not all of the Observables inside it are completing properly. Have you tried adding a `catchError` to see if something is erroring out? Also, I'm not 100% certain you can pass an array to `forkJoin`. Could you try `forkJoin(...data)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach by writing map function inside the `forkJoin`. For details you can check this [link](https://chrisnoring.gitbooks.io/rxjs-5-ultimate/content/cascading-calls.html). Also check this article for best practice of using [forkJoin](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-forkjoin-never-use-array-indexes-in-subscribe-1f4005582ae8)

```
stream.pipe(
  switchMap((user) => {
    return forkJoin(
      from([{ id : 114, user: 1}, { id : 115, user: 1}],
      from([{ id : 200, user: 1}, { id : 201, user: 1}])
    )
  })
```